# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoError: Unrecognized pipeline stage name: '$setWindowFields'

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm trying set the rank for the fields for my mongo documents,

```
const agg = [

{$setWindowFields:{

     sortBy:{"timeSpent":-1},
    output:{
        DefaultScore:{
            $rank:{}
        }
    }
}}]

const newRanksForTimeSpent = await tableName.aggregate(agg)
```

I want my schema to be filtered in descending order and set the rank accordingly.

If anyone could help me with this.

thanks

Comment: May I know what is your MongoDB version? `$setWindowFields` is a new feature available on v5.0+

Comment: I am using mongoose `6.1.2` which supports 5.x.x above mongo DB server according to https://mongoosejs.com/docs/compatibility.html But I am facing the same issue here.

Comment: yes it is not working on my mongo version. I am using 4.4.11